# Official C++ language subsets

Tags: c++, programming-languages

I mainly use C++ to do scientific computing, and lately I've been restricting myself to a very C-like subset of C++ features; namely, no classes/inheritance except complex and STL, templates only used for find/replace kinds of substitutions, and a few other things I can't put in words off the top of my head. I am wondering if there are any official or well-documented subsets of the C++ language that I could look at for reference (as well as rationale) when I go about picking and choosing which features to use.

Comment: What's your rationale for defining a subset of C++? Why not just use the features that help you and leave alone the features that don't. It's potentially a lot of work to define a consistent subset of features; what's the gain?

Comment: Not much really, I was just curious whether this kind of thing has ever been well defined. I like to keep things easily interface-able with C and Fortran, and I wanted some other people's opinions on some of the language features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [Embedded C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C%2B%2B).  It sounds mostly similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: Embedded C++ never caught on; once you've butchered the language that much, it has no advantages over C.

Answer (score 7):

Google publishes its internal C++ style guide, which is often referred to as such a subset: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html .  Ben Maurer, whose company reCAPTCHA was acquired by Google, describes it as follows [in this post on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Why-did-Google-choose-C-over-C-for-most-of-its-code):

> You can basically think of Google's
>   C++ subset as C plus a bit of sugar:
>
> > The ability to add methods to structs
> >
> > Basic single inheritance.
> >
> > Collection and string classes
> >
> > Scope based resource management.

They also publish a lint tool, [cpplint.py.](https://github.com/google/styleguide/tree/gh-pages/cpplint)

Answer (score 5):

Not long ago I listened to this SE-Radio podcast - [Episode 152: MISRA with Johan Bezem](http://www.se-radio.net/2009/12/episode-152-misra-with-johan-bezem/), which introduces MISRA, standard guidelines for C and C++ to ensure better quality, try looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

The GCC developers are about to allow some C++ features. I'm not aware of any official guidelines, yet, but I am pretty sure that they will define some. Have a look at [initial report](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00705.html) on the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL has been using C for writing kernels, but they have recently added (or will soon add) C++ bindings and perhaps Java.  OpenCL leaves out a number of performance robbing features of C.  Excluded are things like function pointers and recursion.  Smart pointers and polymorphism also create overhead.

Restrictions on C:
[SIMD programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417681/simd-programming-languages/1454710#1454710)

Slightly off topic: Here is a good discussion comparing OpenCL with CUDA using C.
[OpenCL or CUDA Which way to go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644979/opencl-or-cuda-which-way-to-go)

Comment: My point being that OpenCL limits what you are allowed to use in C and C++.  Many features are removed or not supported, or offer limited support.  Still, these subsets of those languages are still quite useful and allow you to write all sorts of simulations and software for use on GPGPU's, DSP's, FPGA's, and multicore CPU's.

Answer (score 1):

[The SEI CERT C++ Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88046682) gives a list of rules for writing safe, reliable, and secure systems in C++14. This is not a subset of C++ per se, but as a coding standard like the other answers is a subset in effect by avoiding unsafe, undefined, or easily-misused features (including some common to C).

Answer (score 0):

Well, latest developments (TR1, C++0x) in C++ made it very much generic, allowing you to do imperative, OOP or even (limited) functional programming in C++. Libraries like Boost also enable you to do very power declarative template-based meta-programming.

I think Boost is the first thing to try out in C++. It's a comprehensive library, which also includes several modules that enable you to program in functional style (Boost.Functional) or making compile-time declarative meta-programming (Boost MPL).

Comment: Well, it depends what you call a set -- if just STL, then Boost is a superset indeed. But my point was that Boost.Functional and Boost.MPL are subsets of C++ as a language.

Comment: I originally meant subset as in a subset of the language features itself. Boost seems to require a very comprehensive set of C++ features.